# How can i extract all the element from object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, destructuring

How can I extract the specific column from an object, I have a column array and I want these fields extracted from an object which will be constructed by map loop function which is the item.
Now here, how can check my fields dynamically. i don't want item[col[0]] like this.
please tell me a short cut.

```
const person = [{
  firstName: "Nick",
  lastName: "Anderson",
  age: 35,
  sex: "M"
},
{
  firstName: "yopm",
  lastName: "Geyun",
  age: 36,
  sex: "M"
}]

const col=['firstName' , 'age']

return person.map(item=>{
     var i=0;        
     return [
         //How can i confgure here , that i show stop increment or not.
        item[col[i]],
        item[col[i+1]]
//here i want to fetch my colums['firstName' , 'age] from item {
//{firstName: "Nick",lastName: "Anderson",age: 35,sex: "M"} dynamically.
]   
})
}

console.log(func())
```

How can I configure here, that I show stop increment or not.
        item[col[i]],
        item[col[i+1]]
i want it dynamically

Comment: "Dynamically" means through an Asynchronous activity, like `onclick`. I'm not seeing anything dynamic here.

Comment: I think `dynamically` in this context means `col` or `person` might not be known until run time @StackSlave.

Comment: i want to get values inside:  return [
        values from object ['firstName','age']
]

Comment: After that columns can also change, here I want to make it dynamically configure, how many column values should be display.

Comment: **Mark Meyer** yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over the `col` properties and `.map` to a new array. You could also consider changing the `person` variable name to `people` (or something like that), because it's a *collection* of persons, not a singular person, reducing the chance of confusion:

```js
const people = [{
    firstName: "Nick",
    lastName: "Anderson",
    age: 35,
    sex: "M"
  },
  {
    firstName: "yopm",
    lastName: "Geyun",
    age: 36,
    sex: "M"
  }
]

const col = ['firstName', 'age']

console.log(
  people.map(
    person => col.map(prop => person[prop])
  )
);
```

Comment: Good brother.you saved my day.Thanks